# How to escape ^M from svn:eol-style native

Tags: svn, unix, eol

We have specified `eol-style:native` property in our subversion repository for shell script; this gets rid of `^M` characters which are included when file is edited on Windows and executed on UNIX box.

But recently we ran into an issue:

One shell script had following statement written:

```
sed 's/^M//g' source_file > target_file
```

to replace ^M characters from a data file. But when the script is checked-in in subversion and updated on unix box the statement becomes:

```
sed 's/
//g' source_file > target_file
```

### REAL QUESTION

**I need a way to put ^M character in shell script in subversion with `eol-style:native` property already present. I don't want this specific ^M character to be lost in transition. Is it possible?**

Comment: I'm actually surprised that Subversion affects this because this isn't a <CR><LF>, but just a <CR> character. I would assume this to be a bug in Subversion. What if you change this file to have an `svn:eol-style` of `LF`? Would that affect your sed script? Otherwise, hope your `sed` script is GNU and it'll take a `\r`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [^M on Windows Linux via subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209093/m-on-windows-linux-via-subversion)

Answer (score 1):

use `\r` instead of **^M**

```
sed 's/\r//g' source_file > target_file
```

Comment: Our data files which needs to be modified have `^M` characters; would `\r` get rid of them?

Comment: @SiB ^M is a \r, unless you literally mean a caret + M instead of ctrl+M